# resolv.conf + PXE server + kickstart files

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, pxe

I use PXE server in order to download kickstart and to install Linux.
After installation I saw that `/etc/resolv.conf` was created with the IP of the PXE server.

Why there is PXE server IP address in `resolv.conf`?

Comment: What are network parameters defined in kickstart config file (line starting with `network`).

Answer (score 3):

`resolv.conf` can be modified by your DHCP server, which often times may be the PXE server. You have a pre-configured resolv.conf it can still be modified by DHCP and overwritten or modified.

This link has a good explanation.

[nixCraft: How To: Make sure /etc/resolv.conf never gets updated by DHCP client.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/)